# Don't undestand why my file appears to be unreadable

Tags: python, json, file, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a dictionary to a file.
and when I try to read it back, it returns nothing, as if the file is empty.
I saw the file and there is something written into it.
I think that the way I write is not the best and that's why it does the problem.
my expected outcome is to read the file, get back the dictionary, and write to it. This is how I write:

```
# this function gets the db_name, creating a text file with the db_name
# and creating a empty dictionary with the key that is the table_name.

def __createTheDb(self,dirPath, db_name, table_name):
    global db_file
    os.chdir(dirPath)  #gets into the directory
    print(os.getcwd(), "from create the db")
    db_file = open(db_name + ".txt", "w")
    temp_dict = dict.fromkeys(f"{table_name}".split())
    db_file.write(str(temp_dict))
    return db_file
```

How I write the file:

```
def writeFile(self, db_name, table_name, key, value):
    global db_file, my_json #gets the global variable
    print(type(db_file))
    file = open(db_name,"r").read()
    print(file) #-> the problem is that this prints nothing.
```

I tried to read it with `json.load(db_file)`, but it says it's unreadable.

The problem ->

```
return loads(fp.read(),
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

I just want to convert the text file to dictionary so I can set it's key...

Comment: Where do you close these files you're opening?

Comment: i don't... 0_0, please tell me its not the problem ...

Comment: It looks to me like `db_file` shouldn't be global. You should probably define it in a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). Then the file would be automatically closed.

Comment: Use `with` statements to handle closing of files. Typically you might find that you can't read the content from a file you didn't close after writing it.

Comment: thank you both :) i'm new to python and now will read about 'with' statement but why the db_file shouldn't be global ? I'm using it in a few methods and want to pass it around. so I'll have access to the exact same file

Answer (score 0):

try loading it with

```
with open("./path/file.json", "r") as f:
        loadedDic = json.load(f)
```

then loadedDic will be equal to the dictionary IF the file you loaded is just a dictionary. If it has a list of dictionaries, or a dictionary of dictionaries, etc you'll need to parse it the way you normally parse lists/dicts/etc.

Comment: i get an error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType, the only thing i changed is is the path, to be `db_file`